# Using AddRange from a list causes multiple database trips

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is code I inherited and not my design.

One big query is being made to bring back a list of objects. The query results are then used to create a list of custom objects. There was a ton of looping and exists to get distinct values e.g Counties, States, etc.. In an effort to optimize the code I am attempting to select the distinct values from the query results and add them to the new collection using AddRange. However, this causes a call to SQL for every value.

**THE INITIAL QUERY**

```
        using (var db = new StorageEntities())
        {
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            List<CompanyTitleFeeSchedule> list = db.CompanyTitleFeeScheduleCompanies
                .Include(x => x.Company)
                .Include(x => x.CompanyTitleFeeSchedule)
                .Include(x => x.CompanyTitleFeeSchedule.CompanyTitleFeeScheduleAreas)
                .Include(x => x.CompanyTitleFeeSchedule.CompanyTitleFeeScheduleCompanies)
                .Include(x => x.CompanyTitleFeeSchedule.CompanyTitleFeeScheduleAreas.Select(t => t.County))
                .Include(x => x.CompanyTitleFeeSchedule.CompanyTitleFeeScheduleAreas.Select(t => t.County.State))
                .Where(x => x.CompanyID == id || x.Company.ParentCompanyID == id)
                .Select(x => x.CompanyTitleFeeSchedule).Distinct().ToList();

            return list.Select(item => new VM.CompanyTitleFeeScheduleViewModel(item)).ToList();
        }
```

**In the constructor VM.CompanyTitleFeeScheduleViewModel which has List of CountyViewModel which I am trying to populate with distinct counties from the query results. This results in a call to the database for every distinct county. Even though the values I need are already in the query results. Since the list has already been enumerated why would entity need to go back to the database? **

```
           //Get a list of distinct counties and add them to the collection
            Counties.AddRange((from c in data.CompanyTitleFeeScheduleAreas
                group c by c.CountyID
                into cty
                select cty.First())
                .Select(cty => new CountyViewModel
                {
                    CountyID = cty.CountyID,
                    Name = cty.County.Name,
                    StateID = cty.County.StateID
                }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used EF in a few years, but last I did, you would usually need to use `Include` to load a related entity along with a query. Otherwise, related entities get *lazy-loaded* on demand.

Like:

```
...
.Select(x => x.CompanyTitleFeeSchedule)
.Include(x => x.CompanyTitleFeeScheduleAreas) // added this.
...
```

For more info, see: [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

That post also tells you how to disable lazy-loading in various scenarios.